# Timeline by HTML/CSS for email (gmail...)

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, timeline

How should I write this kind of timeline, using just HTML and CSS? It should work in Gmail and in other mail agents. I wrote different versions, but they do not work.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/da6xL.png

Answer (score 0):

Apologies but your question isn't clear. What are you trying to do?
If you'd like to build that layout within an email you will need to do so using HTML Tables & CSS, separating the elements into cells and rows.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp